# library for mac to load and manipulate 3d objects

Tags: cocoa, xcode, 3d

I am trying to learn the basic of 3d for Mac using Xcode, so I would like to know what could I use to achieve these results :

-load a 3d object (3ds, obj, etc)

-add some interaction (use the mouse to rotate, zoom, pan)

-take a snapshot of the object so it can be saved as image

I know that a library that does it all is not available; but I hope to find suggestions about what i can use.

Has anyone any experience with libraries/frameworks that can help me to achieve these goals? Or tutorials that explains how to do what i am trying to achieve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit [Nate Robbins](http://www.xmission.com/~nate/tutors.html) websight and download the tutorial (with source code) for OS X. In addition to letting you walk through some basic concepts for OpenGL, it contains the source code for loading 3d files in OBJ format (glm.c) in addition to view manipulation routines.

Examples for printing an OpenGL context are here : [Cocoa Builder - OpenGL printing/image](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/80348-opengl-printing-image.html)

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is the technology to use for 3D. There are great tutorials and lots of sample code at [nehe.gamedev.net](http://nehe.gamedev.net/).

Comment: Thanks Seth; what worries me is the learning curve....I would love to learn OGL, but mainly all that i wanna do is a visualizer for the 3d models that i make (for the games i use irrlicht and Unity); and I do not know how complex is OGL to learn just to do this.

Comment: The learning curve is steep, and a mathematical background (in linear algebra and trig) is a *real* good idea. It might help to go to the library and check out an old "3D Game Programming" book that came out >10 years ago (before hardware-accelerated 3D). A few of those books have walkthroughs on writing your own software-based texture mapped 3D engine. Because a software-renderer has to do _everything_, they cover all the math, the transforms, data structures, etc. Someone else might be able to suggest a higher level approach or a more recent book :)

Comment: I think that i own the book that you are talking about...is the one where you build a 3d engine from scratch in c++? The only issue that i have with OGL is the math part :) That's why I am trying to find something already wrapped nicely; this is for a simple desktop app after all.